# Q: Sequence definition of non-convergence (Not diverging definition)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have that convergence requires that the following be true

$$
\forall\epsilon>0\exists N: n\ge N:|a_n-a|<\epsilon
$$

for some sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $a$ for $n\to\infty$.

I want to use the reverse of this requirement. I do not know how to express it but I am guessing

$$
\exists\epsilon>0\forall N:n\ge N:|a_n-a|\ge\epsilon
$$

it is expressed like the above. Can you help me out?

Comment: Seems fine to me if what you want to express is *$\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $a$*. You might want to add some quantifiers for $n\geq N$ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat cleaner definition of the limit of a sequence is:
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, |a_n-a|<\epsilon
$$
Then the opposite is:
$$
\exists \epsilon>0, \forall N\in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \geq N, |a_n-a|\geq\epsilon
$$